# Algolia Magento Configuration

Tags: magento, algolia

I created a application in Algolia for my magento store. Downloaded the extension and set the all the configurations as in the YouTube video tutorial.

> Application ID
>
> Search-only (public) API key
>
> Admin API key

My problem is that when I click on the save config button it shows me an error:

> An error occurred while saving this configuration: Hosts unreachable: Couldn't resolve host 'W0N31U5T1P.algolia.net',Couldn't resolve host 'W0N31U5T1P-1.algolianet.com',Couldn't resolve host 'W0N31U5T1P-2.algolianet.com',Couldn't resolve host 'W0N31U5T1P-3.algolianet.com'